# Datediff query in sql database returning null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find out if a certain date is befere or after a field in a table. So I wrote two queries to test it out.

First was this:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE name='Tareas';
```

This gets me:

```
+--------+----------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+                                                                                                                                            
| name   | user     | proyect               | start_date | update_date | description                | status    | percent | keyid |                                                                                                                                            
+--------+----------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+                                                                                                                                            
| Tareas | spruebas | Y otro proyectito mas | 2014-09-18 | 2014-09-18  | Para que vea algo el pobre | Pendiente |       0 |     5 |                                                                                                                                            
+--------+----------+-----------------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+
```

So then I try it with this test query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-10-09','update_date') AS pepe  FROM tasks WHERE name='Tareas';
```

However this returns pepe as NULL. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't I be getting the difference (positive or negative) of the dates? I know the date formats are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The string `'update_date'` is not a valid date. When referring to columns, omit the quotes or use backticks if it conflicts with a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).

What you want is:

```
DATEDIFF('2014-10-09',update_date)
```